# How to access css file with Tomcat 6 and Spring 3.0.4

Tags: spring, tomcat

I try to access css file by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="META-INF/resources/css/style.css" />
```

Structure:

```
springhibernate
 -META-INF
   -recources
       -css
           -style.css
       -img
 -WEB-INF
    -classes
    -jsp
    web.xml
    application-context.xml
```

web.xml part:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How can I refer to a css file?

Answer (score 0):

The META-INF directory is not accessible using an URL according to the specification. It's purpose is to hold information useful to Java archive tools, xml descriptors, etc.

Create separate top-level directory in your .war file to serve CSS, Javascript, HTML, etc. files.

Note: you can access everything in META-INF in your Java code, using [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)'s getResource and getResourceAsStream calls. The limititation is that it cannot be referenced with a URL.